# i'm trying to check if the dates(startDate,endDate) that the user has chosen already exist in the database using Ajax jquery?

Tags: jquery, ajax, symfony

i'm trying to check if the dates(startDate,endDate) that the user has chosen already exist in the database using Ajax jquery?

```
here is my Controller:
    public function createProperty(Request $request)
     {
        $property = new Property();
        $form = $this->createForm(Property::class, $property);
        $form->handleRequest($request);             
        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {       
             $this->em->persist($property);
             $this->flush();
             $this->addFlash('success', $this->trans('notification.success.create'));
             return $this->redirectToRoute('property.list', [],Response::HTTP_SEE_OTHER);
            }
       return $this->renderForm('property/create.html.twig', ['form' => $form,
]); }
```

here is my view

```
twig code:
    {{ form_start(form, {'attr': {'class': 'custom-validation'}}) }}
                    {{ form_row(form.title) }}
                    {{ form_row(form.type) }}
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col">
                            {{ form_row(form.location) }}
                        </div>
                        <div class="col">
                            {{ form_row(form.surface) }}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col">
                            {{ form_row(form.starDate) }}
                        </div>
                        <div class="col">
                            {{ form_row(form.endDate) }}
                        </div>
                    </div>
    
                    <div class="gap-2 mt-1 text-center">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary waves-effect waves-light">
                            <span class="fas fa-plus"></span> {{ 'create'|trans }}click on thr button, a modal show to inform user that the same dates are already exist in database: 
    i would like to when the user 
                        </button>
                        <button type="reset" class="btn btn-secondary waves-effect">
       <span class="fas fa-undo"></span> {{ }}
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    {{ form_end(form)}}
```

how i can modify the controller methode to verify data?

Answer (score 0):

First we'll add a submit event listener to the form:

```
{{ form_start(form, {'attr': {'class': 'custom-validation', 'onsubmit': 'submitForm(event)'}}) }}
```

Add this script after the form tag:

```
<script>
    // getting form elements
    var startDate = document.getElementById("{{form.startDate.vars.id}}");
    var endDate = document.getElementById("{{form.endDate.vars.id}}");

    //submit event
    function submitForm(event) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "{{ path('some_path') }}",
            method: 'GET',
            data: { startDate: startDate.value, endDate: endDate.value },
            success: function(data) {
                if (data == "Exists") {
                    // open modal logic

                    // prevent submission
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
            }
        })
    }
</script>
```

Create this controller path and set up the repository logic:

```
/**
 * @Route("/some_path", name="some_path", methods={"GET"})
 */
 public function new(Request $request, YourRepository $repository): Response {
    $startDate = $request->query->get("startDate");
    $endDate = $request->query->get("endDate");

    // repository logic
    // DONT FORGET TO FORMAT YOUR DATES.
    $property = $repository->findOneBy(array(
        'startDate' => $startDate, 
        'endDate' => $endDate
    ));

    // returns entity
    if ($property != null) {
        return new Response("Exists");
    }

    return new Response("Does not exist");
}
```

Comment: thanks Ryota Mitarai, i add a div in my view:  <div class="modal" id="myModal">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"><i class="ti-save"></i> Save</button>
            </div>
            {{ form_end(form)}}

Comment: function submitForm(event) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "{{ path('date.availability') }}",
                method: 'GET',
                data: { startDate: startDate.value, endDatet: endDatet.value },
                success: function(data) {
                    if (data == "Exists") {
                        $('#myModal').modal('show');

                        // prevent submission
                        event.preventDefault();
                    }
                }
            })
        }
    </script> but it didn't work

Comment: Sorry @learner, you're not giving me enough information. Did you check the browser console for javascript errors? What does it say and what line is it? By the way, why did you change the variable 'endDate' to 'endDatet'? The name shouldn't be random, it has to be the exact same as your designated entity property's name.